# Laravel 5.1 select field in with function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Can I select value from relationships with function "with" ?
So make something like this:

```
$test = User::where('id',1)->with(['user_detail' => function($query){
            $query->select("detail_1");
        }])->get();
```

Yes I know that I can put select in relation "user_detail" but can I select in with function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select within `with` as you made the example given below:

```
$test = User::where('id',1)->with(['user_detail' => function($query){
    $query->select("detail_1");
}])->get();
```

But it won't not work (as you commented in other answer) because you've only selected a single property but the foreign key is not available in your select statement. So, make sure that, you also select the related foreign key as well and then it'll work.

In your case, I believe that, you've to also select the `user_id` in your select for example:

```
$test = User::where('id',1)->with(['user_detail' => function($query){
    $query->select(
        'user_id', // This is required if this key is the foreign key
        'detail_1'
    );
}])->get();
```

So, without the `foreign key` that makes the relation, `Eloquent` won't be able to load the related models and that's why you get `null` in your result as you mentioned in other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `select()` inside `with()`. Just pass an array of columns:

```
$query->select(['detail_1', 'detail_2']);
```

Alternatively, you can create another relation and add `select()` to it:

```
public function userDatails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserDetail')->select(['detail_1', 'detail_2']);
}
```

Comment: for second solution ok, but for first solution.
Not working form me. It return null on field "user_detail" in model.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = Staff::where('live_status',2)
            ->with('position')->with('department')->with('gender')
            ->with(['partner' => function($query){
                    $query->where('alive',0);
                }]);
```

Comment: Add explanation please.